# Magento upgrade 2.4.3 throws error(Cannot instantiate interface_

Tags: magento, upgrade, instantiation

I am trying to upgrade magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.3, i have update my system-requirements

Php - 7.4
mysql - 8.0
Composer - 2.*

magento 2.4.3 vanila version is working fine for me.

my current project magento version is 2.3.4, now we are upgrading to 2.4.3.

magento 2.4.3 is upgarde, but when i try to run command like sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade, i am getting this error.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface in /var/www/html/aao_2021_sep/store/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:

Help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try to: 1) clear `generated` folder; 2) run `composer dump-autoload` ; 3) check and update if needed magento file permissions: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html#set-file-permissions

Answer (score 3):

What solved this for me was regenerating composer:

rm -rf vendor/*

composer clearcache

composer install

then compile magento (setup upgrade.... cache flush)

Comment: Hi syed, i have tried this one but the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 2.3.3 to 2.4.3 and had same errors, Disabling MSI worked for me referring to https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-magento-msi/

Answer (score 0):

Try `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I was missing this line in app/etc/di.xml :

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator" />
```

You can also compare your file app/etc/di.xml with this : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/etc/di.xml